# How to connect a list to another in Drupal 8 based in text?

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, drupal-modules

First I'm new in Drupal 8, so every answer is kind of important to me.

Well I have 2 fields (list type) in drupal.

I want `onSelectSpecific` value in the one list, navigates me to  specific values in the other list field. Is this possible and how ?

Comment: There is a 'stackoverflow' for Drupal specific questions. https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/ask. You might get a faster response there.

Comment: use conditionnal field module https://www.drupal.org/project/conditional_fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this module will help you:
https://www.drupal.org/project/shs
You can build a two level taxonomy, with this module you can choose the first level and he will show you all the terms under him.